# Get mean of .SD and total number per group in same call?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to get the row number per group with the same call where I take a mean based on group membership. **So I'd like to modify this call to include the `.N` notation to create a new column per group:**

```
d <- dt[!is.na(dt$group),  lapply(.SD, mean), by = group, .SDcols = sd.cols]
```

**Is there a way to do this**?

Here's what I tried:

`d <- dt[!is.na(dt$group),  .(.N, lapply(.SD, mean)), by = group, .SDcols = sd.cols]`

This gives two columns, N and V2, where I have no idea what V2 is but certainly it's not the mean per `sd.cols` as desired.

Comment: (For the future, please provide a reproducible example). You're almost there. Replace `.()` with `c()`. `lapply()` returns a list. To that, you want to add `.N` as a separate column and return another list, not a list-of-list. The base function `c()` concatenates a vector of length-1 and list to a list. That should do it, IIUC.

Comment: @Arun yes that did it thanks very much.

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer it yourself and mark as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write up @Arun's answer, here's what worked:

```
  d <- dt[!is.na(dt$group),  c(.N, lapply(.SD, mean)), by = group, .SDcols = sd.cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do as:

```
iris[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), .N), by = Species]

      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  N
1:     setosa        5.006        3.42        1.462       0.246 50
2: versicolor        5.936        2.74        4.260       1.326 50
3:  virginica        6.588        2.96        5.552       2.026 50
```